# Is it safe to implicitly convert a `uint8_t` (read from a socket) to a `char`?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am confused by the C++ conversion rules regarding unsigned-to-signed and vice versa.

I'm reading data from a socket and saving it in a `std::vector<uint8_t>`. I then need to read a part of it
(assuming it is ASCII data) and save it in a `std::string`. This is what I'm doing:

```
for (std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator it = payload.begin() + start; it < payload.begin() + end; ++it) {
    store_name.push_back(*it);
}
```

So as you can see, `*it` returns a `uint8_t` and passes it into the `push_back` member function of `std::string`, which takes a `char` - thus an implicit conversion occurs. `char` may in fact be either signed or unsigned. I'm not sure what happens if it is signed.

I cannot wrap (no pun intended) my head around what is happening here, and whether or not it is safe.

Does `store_name.push_back(*it)` change the bit-pattern of `*it` before storing it in the `std::string`?
What rules exactly govern this?

I've gone through many places online explaining type-conversion rules, but it still doesn't really stick with me. Explanations will be appreciated.

EDIT: As a different way to put it - **in general, what happens when we cast `unsigned` to `signed` and vice versa?**

```
unsigned char a = 50; // Inside the range of signed char
signed char b = (signed char) a;
```

Is the bit pattern in `b` required to be the same as the bit pattern in `a`? Or may the bit pattern change?

Also, what about the opposite direction:

```
a = (unsigned char) b;
```

Again - does a change to the bit pattern occur? Or is it guaranteed that the underlying bit pattern stays the same, no matter how many signed-unsigned conversion we do, as long as the value is in the correct range?

And does it matter if it's an explicit cast using `(cstyle cast)` or `static_cast<>`, or if it's an implicit cast by assignment?

Comment: I believe C++20 guarantees two's complement and as a result the behavior becomes guaranteed. Although I've yet to see a compiler/architecture where this wasn't safe already (in practice, if not in standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [implicit conversions - Numeric Conversion/Integral conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

**To unsigned**

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the
> smallest unsigned value equal to the source value modulo 2n  where n
> is the number of bits used to represent the destination type. That is,
> depending on whether the destination type is wider or narrower, signed
> integers are sign-extended[footnote 1] or truncated and unsigned
> integers are zero-extended or truncated respectively.

**To signed**

> If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the
> source integer can be represented in the destination type. Otherwise
> the result is implementation-defined (until C++20)the unique value of
> the destination type equal to the source value modulo 2n  where n is
> the number of bits used to represent the destination type. (since
> C++20). (Note that this is different from signed integer arithmetic
> overflow, which is undefined).

So for values in range, there should be no conversion. Otherwise, I interpret it as if your machine represents values as two's complement, there is no changes in the bits for conversion to unsigned (from C++20 also to signed) and implementation defined until C++20. (I am not sure why, but I assume most compilers do not change the value, even though they are allowed to).

---

Regarding **`cstyle-cast` vs `static-cast`**: cstyle-cast performs ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast))

> When the C-style cast expression is encountered, the compiler
> attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this
> order:
>
> a) const_cast<new_type>(expression);
>
> b) static_cast<new_type>(expression), with extensions: pointer or
> reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to
> pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even
> if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the
> private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to
> member to pointer to member of unambiguous non-virtual base;
>
> c) static_cast (with extensions) followed by const_cast;
> d) reinterpret_cast<new_type>(expression);
>
> e) reinterpret_cast followed> by const_cast. The first choice that satisfies the requirements of the respective cast operator is selected, even if it cannot be compiled.

So for `signed<->unsiged` conversions, `cstyle-cast` should be the same as `static_cast`.

---

For **implicit conversion** ([implicit conversions - Order of the conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion))

Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:

> 1. zero or one standard conversion sequence;
> 2. zero or one user-defined conversion;
> 3. zero or one standard conversion sequence.

, where

> A standard conversion sequence consists of the following, in this
> order:
>
> 1. zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue
>    conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, and function-to-pointer
>    conversion;
> 2. zero or one numeric promotion or numeric conversion;
> 3. zero or one function pointer conversion; (since C++17) 4) zero or one
>    qualification adjustment.

and numeric conversion is yet again the conversion quoted on the top.

`static_cast` itself converts between types using a combination of implicit and user-defined conversions ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)). So there should not be any difference between implicit or explicit.

Comment: Hi Mikael, thank you for the detailed answer. So I'm trying to make sure I understand the bottom line here, please correct or validate my understanding: when converting `c` from unsigned to signed (e.g., `uint8_t` to `char` where `char` is signed), as long as the value of `c` is in the numeric range containable in a `signed char`, the value doesn't change. And when converting the opposite direction, the same is still true. And - that is the case both for implicit conversion (e.g., assignment of `x` to a variable), and for explicit ones (i.e. both `static_cast` and `cstyle_cast`). Am I correct?

Comment: @AvivCohn Yes, if it's in the range it's fine both ways, with both static, cstyle and implicit cast.

Comment: Is this true for any type of conversion (either cstyle, `static_cast` or implicit) for any numeric type? I.e. - when converting `T1 a` to `T2 b`, the value of `b` will stay the same as `a` if the value of `a` can be contained inside the numeric range of  `T2`?

Comment: @AvivCohn, do you mean the value or the bit-representation now? `float` and `int` have different representations, but can be (statically) casted between each other (changing bit represenatation). Value should be the same *if* the value is representable in the new type.